# Insertion Sort in R

Tags: r, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to learn about algorithms and implementing them in R. Here is my attempt at an insertion sort:

```
insertion.sort <- function(A){
i <- 0
j <- 0
key <- 0
for (j in 2:length(A)){
key <- A[j]
i <- j-1
if (is.null(i)){return('i is null')}
if (is.null(A[i])){return('A[i] is null')}

while ((i > 0) & (A[i] > key)){
A[i+1] <- A[i]
i <- i-1
}
A[i+1] <- key
}
return(A)
}
```

However, this gives me the error

```
Error in while ((i > 0) & (A[i] > key)) { : argument is of length zero
```

when doing

```
insertion.sort(c(4,2,1))
```

and I don't understand why. I tried even building in the variables appropriately:

```
A <- c(4,2,1)
key <- A[2]
i <- 2-1
(i > 0) & (A[i] < key)

[1] FALSE
```

and this obviously gives me a condition, rather than an error.

Comment: you can debug your function by `debug(insertion.sort)` and then run your `insertion.sort(c(4,2,1))`

Comment: It fails in the second iteration. `i` becomes `0` and so `A[i]` is of length `0`.

Comment: @jogo Thank you, that is very helpful.

Comment: @LyzandeR When `i` becomes `0`, why does the `while` loop still execute?

Comment: @Clarinetist Because the condition on the first line of `while` still needs to be evaluated and the second part  (`A[i] < key]`) fails.

Comment: @LyzandeR Okay. So my guess is that I would have to insert a check after setting `i <- i-1` to make sure `i` isn't less than `1`. Is there an analogue to Python's `break` in R?

Comment: Yes there is and it is called `break` :)

Comment: @LyzandeR Thank you very much!

Comment: For others' reference, I found out that I needed to make `&` short-circuiting, so I simply changed the code from `&` to `&&` and it's fine.